# how to port android native apps into blackberry OS 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I developed an native android application. Now i want to import the application in BlackBerry 10. Please help and also let me know whether i will get any functional or technical issues while importing as well as while deploying into app store.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [the information](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/) you want on official BlackBerry Developer site.